# How can I define more than one Ruby methods in an .rb file without using a module?

Tags: ruby, function, methods, module, definition

Is it possible to define more than one Ruby methods in an .rb file without writing a module?
When I define only one method in an mymethod.rb file with def `mymethod(s) ... end` and I load it with `load 'mymethod.rb'` I can call my defined method without problem. But when I want to define two methods in this way, only the first one is available. I know that I can make a module, but in that case I always have to call my method as `"module_name.method()"`. Isn't there any other way to define more than one method?

Answer (score 1):

It is perfectly OK to define two (or as many as you want) methods in a file. Given I have the following file:

```
# test.rb
def firstMethod
  1
end

def secondMethod
  2
end
```

I can do this in an IRB (through executing `irb` within the directory of the file):

```
irb(main):001:0> require './test.rb'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> firstMethod
=> 1
irb(main):003:0> secondMethod
=> 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Both methods must be available. Make sure there is no typo.

Comment: Still doesn't work for me, it works if and only if the .rb file name is the same as the defined method name. If I define two methods, none of them works any more. I am using Ruby 2.0 and Pry instead of irb, but I think it is not an issue.

Comment: Okay, case closed: I had a copy of the original .rb file, and I edited that with geany, not that one what I loaded to ruby / irb / Pry...

Answer (score 0):

Okay, case closed: I had a copy of the original .rb file, and I edited that with geany, not that one what I loaded to ruby / irb / Pry...